Is There an Equivalent to HttpActionExecutedContext in .NET 8?
I'm in the process of upgrading a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project up to .NET 8, and am running into a compatibility issue with one of the existing methods. The method is shown below.
public override async Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actContext, CancellationToken token)
{
    // If we can't accept gzip
    if ((actContext.Response == null || actContext.Response.Content == null) ||
        (actContext.Request.Headers.AcceptEncoding == null ||
         !actContext.Request.Headers.AcceptEncoding.Any(h => h.Value == "gzip")))
    {
        // Wait till the action is complete
        await base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actContext, token);

        // Exit
        return;
    }

    // Await the content stream
    var contentStream = await actContext.Response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    // Asynchronously push zipped stream to client
    actContext.Response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) =>
    {
        using (contentStream)
        using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
        {
            await contentStream.CopyToAsync(zipStream);
        }
    });

    // Configure the headers
    actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
    actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
}

The problem I'm running into is that HttpActionExecutedContext is not supported anymore. Is there an exact equivalent to it in .NET 8? I've tried using ActionExecutedContext but it doesn't seem to have all the same properties for the Response class. For example .Content doesn't seem to exist anymore as a property of Response.
Any suggestions or documentation on an equivalent class to HttpActionExecutedContext would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Arguably there is no need to roll out your own response compression feature - you can look into using the build-in one - see the Response compression in ASP.NET Core doc. Basically you need to register and enable it:
// ...
// rest of registrations
builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.EnableForHttps = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// middleware registrations ...

app.UseResponseCompression();

// rest of the middleware registrations

For the actual order in the processing pipeline see the Middleware order section of the docs.
If you want still to go with the approach similar to the previous you might need to do something similar to what response logging does - get the current IHttpResponseBodyFeature (i.e. ActionExecutedContextInstance.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>();) and substitute it with your own.

Thanks for the information. I'll see what I can do with both approaches.
